# Is this supposed to happen on a fresh install of ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

[The servers screen (the output of what is happening)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgCvR.jpg)

I don't think this is supposed to happen? It also gets stuck at a percentage (`sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt update`). This is the 3rd time I have installed Ubuntu from scratch, and the first 2 I tried `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop gdm3` and it got stuck at 37% and looked like this.

Comment: Are you sure your computer doesn't have hardware problems ?

Comment: no clue if it gas hardware problems. its got a 14 year old CPU though

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this because you're doing it on the system console, so you have two independent outputs interleaving: text printed by `apt` and service status messages printed by systemd itself. (In theory the latter should have stopped once the system finished booting, but… I think this varies depending on systemd version, and possibly distro configuration as well.)

Specifically, the staggered output is because the "progress bar" feature of `apt` has switched the terminal from its usual "plain text" mode (which implies carriage returns) to a "raw" mode (which does not), so any unexpected output that ends with a plain `\n` doesn't cause the cursor to return to the beginning. (Apt didn't really expect to have other programs write all over its screen, and systemd wasn't meant to keep showing status messages once anything was running on the console...)

So it isn't necessarily broken; though I would still try to figure out why the systemd status messages are showing up (as I said they're technically meant to stop showing up once the system boots and logins are allowed), e.g. maybe check `systemctl list-jobs` to find anything that's still "starting".

(It's possible to immediately disable the status text with `sudo /bin/kill -s RTMIN+21 1`.)

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Ubuntu Server 23.10 and that fixed it. It also would not boot because "Finished wait until snapd is fully seeded" would be there for infinite time.